# Expecting arguments in Mojolicious routes

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

I have two routes in Mojolicious app as follows:

```
my $route = $r->any('/api')->to('API#');

$route->get('/get_data')->to('#process_forms');
$route->get('/get_data/?file=:file&name=:name')->to('#submit_forms');
```

if I go to **/api/get_data** I get redirected to **process_forms** function. I want the app to take me to **submit_forms** function if I pass additional arguments to that same route. for example, url */api/get_data/?file=myfile&name=myname* should call submit_forms function, but that's not the case here.
In both scenarios, process_forms is called.
What option Mojolicious routing provides to help me with this?

Comment: You're attempting to use placeholders within query parameters.  That is not the purpose of placeholders, and even if it did work would likely lead to trouble. 
  Additionally submit_forms sounds like a 'POST'.  So at minimum, perhaps the method for that should be post instead of get.  That would differentiate it from your "get /get_data" endpoint.  Regardless, if there is different functions that they should probably be different routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mojo's router connects [URL and HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) to controllers. The GET and POST parameters are **not** used in routing. This makes sense, because a URL is typically supposed to target a resource by itself.

You have a path `/get_data` you need to send that to **one controller**. From there you want it sounds like you want to do is to go to another controller if you have GET parameters (passed in the URL). You can do this, but it's not normally what you want.

## Just putting a conditional in a controller,

What you normally want when handling get parameters is simply to put them inside a block in the controller, IE,

```perl
my $query = $c->req->query_params
my $file = $query->param('foo');
my $name = $query->param('name');

if ( defined $file && defined $name) {
  # we have file and name
}
else {
  # or we do not
}
```

## Redispatch

But you can always redispatch to a different controller (manually)

```
MyApp::Controller::submit_forms($self);
```

Or, through Mojo,

```
$self->routes->continue("#submit_forms")
```

As a last idea, [you can also make it that the route doesn't match if the post variables aren't there](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Adding-conditions). But, I've never needed to do this.